# Configuring .htaccess files for CakePHP and Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

I have already visited this link:
[Configure .htaccess file for multiple environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931799/configure-htaccess-file-for-multiple-environments)
But it hasn't resolved my problem.

I am unable to access CakePHP folder from Wordpress directory. This is the .htaccess file of my root:

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.svn(/|$)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /myer
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/trunk/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /project/trunk/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is the .htaccess file of "myer" directory:

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.svn(/|$)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /myer
 RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the .htaccess file of "myer/app" directory:

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.svn(/|$)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /myer
 RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
 RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the .htaccess file of "myer/app/webroot" directory:

```
RedirectMatch 404 /\\.svn(/|$)
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /myer
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What I am getting out of these .htaccess files is "Object not found! - Error 404". What am I doing wrong?