# Laravel 4.2 Environments on the same Server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

I've to deploy several instances of a Laravel app to a unique server. Each instance requires a different database configuration. The default Laravel's environment configuration based on hostnames doesn't work for me because all the apps are going to be on the same server, so there's no way to tell which config fiel to use. Here is my `bootstrap/start.php` file:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'development' => array('Ariels-MacBook-Pro.local'),
    'server' => array('srv-hostname'),

));
```

It would be great that I can define the environment based upon a domain (because my apps area gonna be on diferent domains), so in this way I can define a different config for each domain (hosted on the same server)

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using Nginx? or Apache?

Comment: Ok, Im not sure how you do this with Apache, but in Nginx you can set environment variables in your location blocks. Meaning a different variable for different sub-domains, domains or url patterns. Then get this variable in your `detectEnvironment` method. There must be a way to do the equivalent in Apache. Maybe someone else here will know. If not look that up maybe.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902433/setting-environment-variables-for-accessing-in-php) may help you combined with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886683/htaccess-in-multiple-environments)

Comment: so this is the same app, or diffrent app's on the same server?? i would look at the app/config file and make different config builds for each instance type (this is assuming your build is hosted like /var/www/laravel/ (diffrent apps here))

Comment: It is the same app, but in different folders, for example /var/www/app1/ /var/www/app2/ /var/www/app3/ . How do I make different config builds ?

Answer (score 6):

Laravel's `detectEnvironment` method has a nify feature where you can progamatically determine the current enviornment with a closure.  For example, this would configure Laravel to **always** use the local enviornment.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    return 'local';
});
```

The domain name should be somewhere in $_SERVER, so something like this untested pseudo-code should get you what you want.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
    {
        case: 'example.com':
            return 'production';
        case: 'another.example.xom':
            return 'production';                    
        default:
            return 'local'; //default to local
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it safe? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/upgrade For security reasons, URL domains may no longer be used to detect your application environment. These values are easily spoofable and allow attackers to modify the environment for a request. You should convert your environment detection to use machine host names (hostname command on Mac, Linux, and Windows).

Comment: I guess for safety you can check the host name first: `if(gethostname() == 'server-name')` and then you can check the url as Alan showed above.

Answer (score 0):

My option, in file `app/config/database.php` add this line at the end

```
            'enviorement' => 'local',
            // 'enviorement' => 'development', // this is for dev
            // 'enviorement' => 'production', // this is for production
```

and then access from your controller with this

```
            $env = Config::get('database.enviorement');
            echo $env;
```

`database.php` file is different, you have for ur local another for developemet server and another for producction because there is the "database conection" so i used it to implicit write the enviorement.

Have fun.